# Python input() call blocks other threads from printing to console

Tags: python, multithreading

Thread1: Just blocks on user-input, and then adds the input to a queue before going back to blocking.
Thread2: Prints to console.

I don't see Thread2 outputs unless I enter something on the console. i.e unblock thread1. Is there a way to output to console while also blocking on input in another thread?

```
import threading
import time

def reader():
    while(1):
        text=input()
def writer():
    while(1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Thread 2")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=reader)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=writer)

t1.start()
t2.start()

while(1):
    #Do nothing
    time.sleep(1)
```

Environment: Windows, WPy 3.6.7

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, thread2 is printing as well when thread1 is blocked on input. What is your environment? It may be the matter. I tested your code example on Ubuntu with system interpreter.

Comment: For what it is worth, I was able to reproduce this issue as well. input also blocks other threads from printing on my system (windows server 2012 & python 3.10). Perhaps it is a windows thing.